# Can I post a question about DNS settings on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My domain register is preventing me from accessing the settings that I need to update. Can I format a question for this on SO?

Comment: No, but there are alternatives. I assume superuser would be a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think SuperUser will be beneficial for you.

See https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dns

But there are [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns?sort=newest&pagesize=50) on Stack Overflow also.

See first is there any question on both answers you. If not, then do ask your question on SO or SU as per your need.

If you requires code setting related queries then ask on SO else ask on SU.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about DNS settings would probably be better asked on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions).